# Format continously updating output to variable then query string

Tags: python, stdin

A command I have 'ibeacon scan' gives me the output of this:

```
ibeacon scan...
3F234454-CFD-4A0FF-ADF2-F4911BA9FFA6 1 4 -71 -69
3F234454-CFD-4A0FF-ADF2-F4911BA9FFA6 6 2 -71 -63
3F234454-CFD-4A0FF-ADF2-F4911BA9FFA6 1 4 -71 -69
3F234454-CFD-4A0FF-ADF2-F4911BA9FFA6 5 7 -71 -64
```

I need each of these values to be sent by query string like.

```
UUID=3F234454-CFD-4A0FF-ADF2-F4911BA9FFA6&Major=1&Minor=4&Power=-71&RSSI=-63
```

I am assuming I need to use a delimiter to separate the input individual.

```
for line in fileinput.input():
   string = line
   string2 = string.split(" ")
```

Is this an efficient way to do this? How do I get this output sent by query string?

Comment: Aside from the completely unnecessary temporary name `string`, looks fine. Why don't you try writing the rest of it? You barely seem to have got anywhere.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
import fileinput

pattern = 'UUID={}&Major={}&Minor={}&Power={}&RSSI={}'

for line in fileinput.input():
  query = pattern.format(*line.strip().split(' '))
  # now do something with query
```